# Vaadin 14 components not show up / not visible

Tags: java, spring, polymer, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm developing new module in our application using vaadin14 components (eg https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-date-picker). Everything worked pretty well, but after adding few components (text fields, grids, buttons, labels, notifications etc..) vaadin decided to not listen to me anymore... ;(

Everything started when I've tried to add some addon - slider (because for some reason it was removed from vaadin14). Even I tried a bounch of different addons none of them seem to work, it always lead to not displaying component(it was visible in html code when I was checking html elements on website, but size of that elements always was 0x0 - even setting its size in style didn't seem to work, because - yes it took some place on gui, but was invisible).

I thought that it might be some issue with my vaadin version or some deprecated addons and I've returned to work with default vaadin components. But this time it not seem to work as well. Currently the same issue is with IntegerField, NumberField, DatePicker, ProgressBar and I think that there is much more. There are no errors in console, no errors from server side, html elements are visible in generated html but its size is always 0x0 or not visible(eg vaadin-data-picker 0x0 [data-picer 0x0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo4UC.png)).

Eg.:
[html egxample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKFtX.png)

Like you can see there are no styles visible or whatsoever..
Code that should generete them looks like that(it is taken straight from vaadin example):

```
    IntegerField integerField = new IntegerField("Age");
    integerField.setSizeFull();
    integerField.setVisible(true);
    add(integerField);
    NumberField numberField = new NumberField("Years of expertise");
    numberField.setSizeFull();
    numberField.setVisible(true);
    add(numberField);
    DatePicker labelDatePicker = new DatePicker();
    labelDatePicker.setLabel("Label");
    DatePicker placeholderDatePicker = new DatePicker();
    placeholderDatePicker.setPlaceholder("Placeholder");
```

I've tried everything - using .setSizeFull(), setVisible(true), rebuilding project with mvn clean install (production and dev mode), deleting node_modules, targer, webpack.generated.js, package-lock.json(both on main directory and module directory) to let vaadin recreate them. But nothing seem to help. On different machine we was able to display NumberField after few rebuilts, but after few more it disapears again...

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Check the difference between working and not woring element:
[Working element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7FyT.png)
[Not working elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ5My.png)
Like you can see above in working element is bunch of stuff like shadow-root, styles, div etc. I assume that other elements also should consist such.

Answer (score 1):

Try with setSizeUndefined() or use fixed sizes instead, or make absolutely sure all the parent layers also have full size.

When you use setSizeFull() you are telling the component to spread out to use all the available space, but if there is any container parent in there that has undefined size, that one will only use as much space as the contents demand -- which is nothing, if the contents are all set to full size. All the available space of nothing is nothing.

Comment: Setting size to undefined or using fixed sizes didn't make difference at all. Setting fixed size only extends invisible field. Moreover I don't think that it is style issue, but maybe something in configuration or something else... But I don't really know where to look for an issue.

Comment: Important thing might be that TextField for example works like a charm, but NumberField not at all

Comment: If you type `customElements.get("vaadin-date-picker")` (or whichever element tags you are having problems with) to the browser console, do you get something else than `undefined` as a result? Could be that custom element definitions haven't been loaded for some reason.